# VS Code git Source Control Error git rev-parse --git-dir

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code v 1.53.2 in windows x64. My code majority in javascript. when I clicked git source control, its output `git rev-parse --git-dir` a million times. [Here it is what its looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h4tT.png)

Comment: I don't think that's an *error*. `git rev-parse --git-dir` produces, as its output, the place the Git directory lives. It's not at all obvious why it would *keep* doing it, since the output is not going to change from moment to moment, though.

Comment: then, how to shut it down so I can see the change through it?

Comment: it makes my computer force itself doing hard work (while actually I do nothing)

Comment: I have no idea how to make it behave better. I avoid Windows as much as possible and have never had to use this combination.